# In clause in Query

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ESRI JavaScript API 3.6. I want to perform a query operation on the fields  returned by the rest service. As far as I know and have read, we can use like and = operators to query single values. But how do I pass more than one value to query?

In my app, I have a world map that highlights about 4-5 countries on load. Is there a way where I can say query.where="COUNTRY in 'india,us,uk'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the `IN` operator in my JS apps to provide a `where` clause to the `Export Item` REST endpoint.  I would imagine if `IN` works there it would also work for the `Query Item` endpoint, which is called by the `Query` object in JS.

I used `IN` to query specific OBJECTID's in my dataset to be exported (you can't give a list of ID's to the `Export Item` endpoint like you can with a `Query`).  I simply made my where clause = `OBJECTID IN (1234,3333,5555,...);`.

Comment: Super it works fine